# How do I set this.location.href to a specific subdomain location

Tags: javascript

This is a version of Gatekeeper, I'm trying to get this to go to a subdomain of my website but it only goes to specific files on my main domain. Basically I enter 404 and it takes me to: *http://mysite.com/404.html* and I want it to go to: *http://**subdomain**.mysite.com/404.html* I'm kinda new to this but I think I need to change

> if (password) { this.location.href = password + ".html"; }

to where the this.location.href doesn't read my current url but the url I specifically want.

Here is the full example code:

```
<HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>My Page</TITLE>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript"><!--
/*********************************************************
             GateKeeper v2.3 - by Joe Barta
            http://www.pagetutor.com/keeper/
     Permission is granted to freely use this script.
**********************************************************/

function GateKeeper() {
   var password = prompt("Password required:", "");
   if (password) { this.location.href = password + ".html"; }}

//--></SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY>

<A HREF="javascript:{;}" onClick="GateKeeper(); return false">Click here</A> for my secret page!  

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does the subdomain name come from?

Comment: Also, that is equivalent to ZERO security on your web page.

Comment: Hey, it's 1994 again!

Comment: Its from my domain but what is the best way to password secure it without making it a pain to download for users?